# Best way to create an empty object in JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, json

To create an empty JSON object I do usually use:

```
json_encode((object) null);
```

casting null to an object works, but is there any other preferable way and/or any problem with this solution?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

#### Recommended method

`json_decode ("{}")` will return a `stdClass` per default, using the below should therefor be considered safe/portable and correct.

```
json_encode (new stdClass);
```

---

---

#### Your solution could work..

The documentation specifies that `(object) null` will result in an empty object, some might therefor say that your code is valid and that it's the method to use.

> [**PHP: Objects - Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)
>
> If a value of any other type is converted to an object, a new instance of the stdClass built-in class is created. If the value was NULL, the new instance will be empty.

**.. but, try to keep it safe!**

Though you never know when/if the above will change, so if you'd like to be 100% certain that you will always will end up with a `{}` in your encoded data you could use a hack such as:

```
$empty = json_decode ("{}");
$result = json_encode($empty); // "{}"
```

Even though it's tedious and ugly I do assume/hope that json_encode/json_decode is compatible with one another and always will evaluate the following to true:

```
$a = <something>;

$a === json_decode (json_encode ($a));
```

Comment: The first line of code has the perfect answer to the general question that most of us are looking for when search leads us here.

Answer (score 109):

If you use objects as dynamic dictionaries (and I guess you do), then I think you want to use an [ArrayObject](https://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php).

**It maps into JSON dictionary even when it's empty.** It is great if you need to distinguish between lists (arrays) and dictionaries (associative arrays):

```
$complex = array('list' => array(), 'dict' => new ArrayObject());
print json_encode($complex); // -> {"list":[],"dict":{}}
```

You can also manipulate it seamlessly (as you would do with an associative array), and it will keep rendering properly into a dictionary:

```
$complex['dict']['a'] = 123;
print json_encode($complex); // -> {"list":[],"dict":{"a":123}}

unset($complex['dict']['a']);
print json_encode($complex); // -> {"list":[],"dict":{}}
```

**If you need this to be 100% compatible *both* ways**, you can also wrap `json_decode` so that it returns `ArrayObjects` instead of `stdClass` objects (you'll need to walk the result tree and recursively replace all the objects, which is a fairly easy task).

**Gotchas**. Only one I've found so far: `is_array(new ArrayObject())` evaluates to `false`. You need to find and replace `is_array` occurrences with `is_iterable`.

Answer (score 16):

Well, [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) simply returns a string from a PHP array/object/etc. You can achieve the same effect much more efficiently by doing:

```
$json = '{}';
```

There's really no point in using a function to accomplish this.

**UPDATE**
As per your comment updates, you could try:

```
$test = json_encode(array('some_properties'=>new stdClass));
```

Though I'm not sure that's any better than what you've been doing.

Answer (score 6):

`json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` will do it too. see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Thanks... But, keep in mind that this solution also convert non-indexed array to object with key value pairs. E.g.: `json_encode(['a', 'b'], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)` would return `{"0": "a", "1": "b"}`

Comment: To better elaborate on the previous comment, this code would indeed produce an array... but it would force **all** arrays into JSON objects, which may not be desirable behavior.