# Python empty dictionary and PHP

Tags: php, dictionary

I cannot find solution, so I am using XML-RPC protocol for getting data from the server and I need to request one command which server requires empty dictinary (" like this {} ", in python I can do it) but in PHP how can I make a request with empty dictionary in PHP?

```
server.list("Example", {}, user_id) //PYTHON
```

this above line works in Python and I got successful response from the server

BUT

```
$client->query("list", "Example", {}, $user_id); // PHP
```

this above line is not working and gives me error. I tried empty array but the server's response was that I have to give dictionary not array.

And I tried

```
$empty = array(""=>"");
$client->query("list", "Example", $empty, $user_id);
```

In this line the result was empty array, no any errors.
I tried also with "NULL" and "" ( empty string ) but no any results and error!

How can execute this command in PHP like in a Python? Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to create an empty object in JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595627/best-way-to-create-an-empty-object-in-json-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `(object) null` to get an 'empty' object. [See here](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting):

> If an object is converted to an object, it is not modified. If a value
>   of any other type is converted to an object, a new instance of the
>   stdClass built-in class is created. **If the value was NULL, the new
>   instance will be empty.**

Comment: You should accept it as a response then! (the green check) :-)

Comment: Yes I know but the system said I have to wait 3 mins :)

Answer (score 2):

`new stdClass();` is the equivalent of an empty object.