# Elastic JSON query to PHP associative array and empty objects

Tags: php, post, elasticsearch, associative-array

I have this Elastic search query which works fine, but I am unable to translate this completely into a PHP associative array.

```
POST /index/type/_search
{
  "fields": [
   "url"
   ],
  "query": {
     "query_string": {
         "default_field": "content.content",
         "query": "german"
      }
   },
  "highlight": {
      "fields": {
         "content.content": {}
       }
  }
}
```

How are `fields` and `highlight` sections in the above `POST` represented in the PHP associative array? My attempt below, where all works except `/* ERROR */`:

```
$params = [
  'index' => $index_name,
  'type' => 'type_name',
  'body' => [
    'fields' => 'url'      /* ERROR */ 
    'query' => [
        'query_string' => [
            'default_field' => 'content.content',
            'query' => $search_term
        ]
    ],
    'highlight' => [
        'fields' => ['content.content'=> []]   /*  ERROR */
    ]
  ]
];
```

Of course, with the above `$params`, I will be doing:

```
$results = Elastic_PHP_client->search($params);
```

Comment: `'fields' => [0=>'url']` and `'fields' => ['content.content'=> '']`. Try it

Comment: Thank you! It nearly works, the errors are gone, but in the response from Elastic, there is no highlight section. Could be a separate issue, perhaps?

Comment: Since your highlight section have no value that's why there is no highlight section

Comment: An empty `highlight` section returned highlighted search terms when I tried the `POST` with the Sense Chrome plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have hit the `[]` vs `{}` distinction problem in PHP.

If at some point the client does `json_encode`, then do it like this:

```
$params = [
  'index' => $index_name,
  'type' => 'type_name',
  'body' => [
    'fields' => ['url'],
    'query' => [
        'query_string' => [
            'default_field' => 'content.content',
            'query' => '$search_term' /* Be carefull, not interpolated */
        ]
    ],
    'highlight' => [
        'fields' => ['content.content'=> new stdClass] /* Will give you '{}' */
    ]
  ]
];
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8595884/118593

Comment: Doing `'fields' => ['content.content'=> new stdClass]` in `highlight` helped! Otherwise, the `highlight` section was not appearing in the search results. Empty objects in JSON this way, I never knew!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the string is not interpolated, I have corrected it now

Comment: Consider using https://github.com/ongr-io/ElasticsearchDSL helper for writing queries. Removes a lot of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
var_export(json_decode($json, true));
```

Which yields usable PHP code:

```
array (
  'fields' =>
  array (
    0 => 'url',
  ),
  'query' =>
  array (
    'query_string' =>
    array (
      'default_field' => 'content.content',
      'query' => 'german',
    ),
  ),
  'highlight' =>
  array (
    'fields' =>
    array (
      'content.content' =>
      array (
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Elegant, but no `highlight` section in the search result/response back from Elastic :(.