# How can I make a nested array tree into an nested object tree?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code:

```
$adjacencies = array (  "0" => array(   "name1" => "pear",
                                        "name2" => "jack",
                                        "data" => array()   ),
                        "1" => array(   "name1" => "pear",
                                        "name2" => "john",
                                        "data" => array()   )
                    );

$final_array['adjacencies'] = $adjacencies;
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($final_array));
```

And this is the result of code above:

[image]

As you see `data`'s value is `[]`, while I want this `{}` instead. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to create an empty object in JSON with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595627/best-way-to-create-an-empty-object-in-json-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not sure what's the reason behind your question,
instead of setting the `data` key as an array, simply define it as a **new object**.

```
$adjacencies = array (  "0" => array(   "name1" => "pear",
                                        "name2" => "jack",
                                        "data" => new stdClass()   ),
                        "1" => array(   "name1" => "pear",
                                        "name2" => "john",
                                        "data" => new stdClass()   )
                    );

$final_array['adjacencies'] = $adjacencies;
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_encode($final_array));
```

**Source:**

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#107071

Answer (score 1):

You could use ArrayObject if it suits you (or stdClass).

[PHP Manual for ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)

For example:

```
php > echo json_encode([[],[]]);
[[],[]]
php > echo json_encode([ new ArrayObject(), new ArrayObject()]);
[{},{}]
```