# Escape Json Object in a Json response in a special condition

Tags: php, android, json

I have a JSON response coming from a Website's Wordpress, and i'm taking this feed from a JSON API.

i have a field called `thumbnail_images`, this field in some posts shows up as a `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject` which causes the App to catch an exception caused by malformed JSON.

Link for it: http://ibelieveinsci.com/?json=get_category_posts&id=3213&page=1&count=3

Searching for the field's name will show the field as Object and in one case where the post has no thumbnail..etc as an empty `JSONArray`.

Is it possible to avoid it? from Client as from PHP side it's impossible, as ive already tried to put the value as an Object when the array is null.

PHP code in the JSON's API's file `post.php`

```
$this->thumbnail_images = $attachment->images;
if(is_null($this->thumbnail_images)){
    $this -> thumbnail_images = json_encode(json_decode ("{}"));
}
```

From Android Side, i'm creating an Object which has the fields names, and doing the response vie Retrofit2.

Comment: Was able to solve it by removing the whole field if it's null. not the best solution, but still

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are doing good.

You can use the options for json_encode to force as an Object instead of Array.

Please find the below code which you can try.

```
$this->thumbnail_images = $attachment->images;
if(is_null($this->thumbnail_images)){
    $this -> thumbnail_images = json_encode(json_decode ("{}"),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hello, the solution didn't work, it kept showing it as an empty Array.

Comment: As i can see the json for thumbnail_images field is showing as object Can you check [here](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=428fe221679114fc9bdf7a54f8fb7115)

Comment: Oh sry! but still the error was not solved.  Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Comment: Is it possible you to share the sample of the php snippet so that I can look into and help you to solve?

Comment: can you also try this code hope this helps,  `json_encode(json_decode("{}",true), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16665216/9034824) suggests using an ArrayObject() for an empty JSON Object when encoding JSON in PHP.

In terms of avoiding it from the client side, you could try using a try-catch like so (NOT tested):

```
try{
    JSONObject thumbnailImages = json.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
    //process images here
} catch (JSONException e){
    //thumbnail images is empty, so returning a JSONArray
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This differs from the Retrofit calling way, where i don't have the ability to get the objects from the response. the library does it on itself.

Comment: Ahhh okay. So can you only edit the PHP so that the JSON is formatted correctly then?

Comment: Is the `$attachment->images` (and by extension `$this->thumbnail_images`) definitely null, or is it returning an empty object/array? Could you try `var_dump`ing it?

Comment: It's null, but doesn't include anything so it shows an array instead of an object. the question is: Why? why not just showing null/empty, as im handling this case. but instead, showing a different type of data.