# Array to JSON conversion resulting empty in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array. I want to convert that array to JSON. I'm using `json_encode` but it's not working.

Here is the code that I'm using.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
include '../panel/config/conn.php';
include '../panel/config/helper_functions.php';

$postions = array(1 => "Goalkeeper", 2 => "Defender", 3 => "Midfielder", 4 => "Forward");
$result = array();
$tmp = get_football_assets($conn);

foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {
    $pair = strtolower($value['pair']);
    $value['pair'] = $pair;
    $value['position'] = $postions[$value['position_id']];
    unset($value['position_id']);
    $result[$pair] = $value;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

** Below Function have been written in helper_functions.php **

```
function get_football_assets($con){
    $data = array();
    $sql = "SELECT nationality, birthdate, birthcountry, birthplace, height, weight, players.position_id as position_id, players.image_path as image_path, teams.name as club, countries.name as country, feed.pair as pair, feed.fullname as name, feed.price as price from players JOIN feed ON feed.player_id = players.api_id JOIN teams ON teams.api_id = players.team_id JOIN countries ON countries.api_id = players.country_id";
    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = $rows;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

If I do `print_r($result)` then it shows the following result but I'm only showing 3 records since the output has more than 1500 records :-

```
[sergeaurier95094] => Array
        (
            [nationality] => C�te d'Ivoire
            [birthdate] => 24/12/1992
            [birthcountry] => C�te d'Ivoire
            [birthplace] => Ouragahio
            [height] => 176 cm
            [weight] => 76 kg
            [image_path] => https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/players/22/95094.png
            [club] => Tottenham Hotspur
            [country] => C�te d'Ivoire
            [pair] => sergeaurier95094
            [name] => Serge Aurier
            [price] => 10.00
            [position] => Defender
        ),

[davinsons�nchezmina26294] => Array
        (
            [nationality] => Colombia
            [birthdate] => 12/06/1996
            [birthcountry] => Colombia
            [birthplace] => Caloto
            [height] => 187 cm
            [weight] => 81 kg
            [image_path] => https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/players/22/26294.png
            [club] => Tottenham Hotspur
            [country] => Colombia
            [pair] => davinsons�nchezmina26294
            [name] => Davinson S�nchez Mina
            [price] => 10.00
            [position] => Defender
        ),

[lucasrodriguesmouradasilva95998] => Array
        (
            [nationality] => Brazil
            [birthdate] => 13/08/1992
            [birthcountry] => Brazil
            [birthplace] => S�o Paulo
            [height] => 172 cm
            [weight] => 72 kg
            [image_path] => https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/soccer/players/30/95998.png
            [club] => Tottenham Hotspur
            [country] => Brazil
            [pair] => lucasrodriguesmouradasilva95998
            [name] => Lucas Rodrigues Moura da Silva
            [price] => 10.00
            [position] => Midfielder
        )
```

`echo json_last_error_msg();` is returning **Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded.**

**Edit**
array_map I have removed as suggested and I'm using `mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');` but it cannot convert characters like **alissonrams�sbecker129820, davinsons�nchezmina26294, nabydecoke�ta32640 etc. etc.**

```
echo bin2hex($pair); gives me the following output :-
6875676f6c6c6f72697331303134

6d696368656c766f726d393737

746f6279616c64657277656972656c64393838

73657267656175726965723935303934

62656e646176696573393839

64616e6e79726f736531323731

646176696e736f6e73e3816e6368657a6d696e613236323934

6b696572616e747269707069657231303136

6a616e766572746f6e6768656e393135

6b796c6577616c6b65722d70657465727334363539

62616d6964656c65616c6c69393232

63687269737469616e64616e6e656d616e6e6572696b73656e393932

6572696364696572393136

6572696b6c616d656c61393431

6c75636173726f647269677565736d6f757261646173696c76613935393938

6d6f75737361736973736f6b6f31333830

686172727977696e6b7331373131

68617272796b616e65393937

6665726e616e646f6c6c6f72656e7465746f7272657331363332

6865756e672d6d696e736f6e34333133

6c756b65616d6f733130363830

7061756c6f64696e6f67617a7a616e69676131343131

766963746f7277616e79616d6131313732

6a75616e6d6172636f73666f797468333335373035

616c66696577686974656d616e333430333436

67656f7267656d61727368353430303835
```

Actually the problem was `strtolower`. So the updated code which works fine for me is below :-

```
foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    $pair = mb_strtolower($value['pair']);
    $value['pair'] = $pair;
    $value['position'] = $postions[$value['position_id']];
    unset($value['position_id']);
    $result[$pair] = $value;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Please provide code that reproduces the problem, with the array encoded in PHP syntax, not as the output of `print_r`.

Comment: Add this after json_encode to know exactly what is the error: `switch (json_last_error()) { case JSON_ERROR_NONE: echo ' - No errors'; break; case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH: echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded'; break; case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH: echo ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch'; break; case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR: echo ' - Unexpected control character found'; break; case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX: echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON'; break; case JSON_ERROR_UTF8: echo ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'; break; default: echo ' - Unknown error'; break; }`

Comment: Or just `echo json_last_error_msg();`  :-)

Comment: Isnt this is discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595627/best-way-to-create-an-empty-object-in-json-with-php

Comment: @Nihir Uhm… OP *doesn't* want an empty object…

Comment: FWIW, `array_map('utf8_encode', $rows)`: *yuck!* See https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/476 how to get UTF-8 directly from your database.

Comment: ^^  that call of `utf8_encode` is almost certainly the cause of your problems.

Comment: @trincot It *should* result in valid UTF-8 though, even if the contents may be garbled…

Comment: @Alek Look for *non-ASCII* strings in your results (i.e. anything "not English") and show us a sample/experiment with those items.

Comment: Try using iconv to convert to UTF8 `function convertUtf8(&$value, $key){
    $value = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($value),"UTF-8//IGNORE", $value);
}

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 array_walk($row, 'convertUtf8');
 $data[] = $row;
}`

Comment: @Kevin Ugh, why?! Set your database connection properly to UTF-8 and none of that is necessary. And `mb_detect_encoding` is by definition absolutely unreliable.

Comment: @deceze check I have changed the sample array

Comment: Go through the duplicates for setting yourself up to use UTF-8 properly.

Comment: @deceze I'm using ```mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');``` instead of ```array_map``` so It's fine except this cases like **davinsons�nchezmina26294, alissonrams�sbecker129820**.

Comment: Are those values properly stored in the database in the first place? Do `echo bin2hex($string)` on one of those strings to see what its actual bytes are.

Comment: @deceze I did ```echo bin2hex('nabydecoke�ta32640');``` and it returned **6e6162796465636f6b65efbfbd74613332363430**.

Comment: If you do that with a hardcoded, copy-pasted string, there's no knowing whether that's useful in any way. You will need to use `bin2hex` on one of your results directly.

Comment: @deceze So You want me ```echo bin2hex($string)``` inside the loop??

Comment: Yes, we need the value of the raw string.

Comment: @deceze In my database it is set to **utf8_general_ci**

Comment: check the updated question

Comment: @deceze hey actually I understand the problem it is happening because of ```strtolower```.