# How to return empty json as {} in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I'm trying to return `{}` but when I do this (based on my research):

```
return json_encode([], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

it returns `"{}"` instead of `{}` only, without the double quotes.

Any idea?

---

Laravel version: 5.5

Comment: Check if this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595627/best-way-to-create-an-empty-object-in-json-with-php

Comment: @Laerte I already tried that, same result.

Comment: JSON is always string. Are you trying to return an object? If so do `json_decode("{}")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by this code:

```
json_decode('{}')
```

Comment: Or simply `new \stdClass`